Triple boot Windows 11 with Ubuntu 20.04 and 24.04
My laptop came pre-installed with Windows 11. A few years back, I made it a dual boot system and installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I now want to install Ubuntu 24.04 while retaining 20.04. Can the Ubuntu installation software handle it? Specificallly, will the GRUB menu be updated correctly so that I can choose between Ubuntu 24.04, Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 11.
I am not looking to share /home across the Ubuntu's, though I might share /swap.

If you do not hibernate which is not recommended anyway, you can share swap. I do not have Windows & multiple installs, but have many Kubuntu installs with some test instals of other systems on two drives. Some now old & I have to turn off os-prober and add boot stanzas only for the current installs into 40_custom. Better to separate data from /home so you can share data. Back with XP, I had two data partitions, one NTFS and one Linux format. Make sure you have good backups of Windows & current installs and use Something else or manual install to create new / (root) partition.

This current system is dual boot; a windows 11 install, a Ubuntu next release that I'm using now & most of the time (currently oracular or what will 24.10 on release) and a LTS release that is currently Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (only recently was 22.04). As @oldfred has said you can share swap partition IF you don't hibernate; though I have removed my swap partition & now use swapfile only (both my next & LTS storing those files on my LTS partition so they're using the same swapfile now; I don't hibernate).  Default grub install works for me (I rarely use windows though)

I run multiple Ubuntu releases on a Windows machine without problems. The EFI partition does not even have any changes. The stub EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg will have to point to one of your Ubuntu roots, and this means that when the other root gets a kernel update, it will not be seen until the ubdate-grub has been run on the root the EFI uses. No big deal if you don't, you'll just be running an old kernel.
I haven't changed the /etc/default/grub line
#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
and the prober runs just fine.

Thank you all for responding. I was able to do a triple boot with Win11, Ubuntu20.04 and Ubuntu 24.04. Ubuntu installer did detect both Win 11 and 20.04 and asked if I wanted to install 24.04 along with these OSes and wanted to choose to boot to any one of them. This was the nice part.

But, it complained about BitLocker preventing it from installing 24.04 and asked to disable it from Win11. This is strange given that I already had 20.04 installed. After disabling BitLocker, I was able to install. But, the installer did not give me a choice to create a partition on the unallocated space and I had to use Gparted to do it. The manual installation option looked quite unintelligible to me, though it probably would have taken care of it.
